# How can I make 2 or more columns of the same type have have unique value combinations MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have these two tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `locations`(
    `location_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `routes`(
    `route_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `location_id_1` INT NOT NULL,
    `location_id_2` INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`location_id_1`) 
        REFERENCES `locations` (`location_id`)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`location_id_2`) 
        REFERENCES `locations` (`location_id`)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE KEY(`location_id_1`, `location_id_2`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`route_id`)
);
```

I would like if on the `routes` table there is this records:

```sql
+---------------+---------------+
| location_id_1 | location_id_2 |
+---------------+---------------+
|             1 |             2 |
+---------------+---------------+
```

Then the following record should not be allowed:

```
+---------------+---------------+
| location_id_1 | location_id_2 |
+---------------+---------------+
|             2 |             1 |
+---------------+---------------+
```

Please let me know how I can solve this even if it means I have to restructure my tables. Please not, I am also avoiding having to use trigger statements

Comment: What's making the second record not allowed? Is it the existence of 1 or 2 in either columns? or both? (1,2) is not the same as (2,1) so it might help if there's additional context especially if restructuring of schema is on the, uhm, table. :)

Comment: If the combination of 1 and 2 has already been set on either column, then it should not be allowed on following records.

Comment: Solution 1 - functional unique index. Solution 2 - unique index and trigger which swaps the values if value1 > value2. Solution 3 - unique index + CHECK constraint. There are more solutions...

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE `locations`(
    `location_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `routes`(
    `route_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `location_id_1` INT NOT NULL,
    `location_id_2` INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`location_id_1`) 
        REFERENCES `locations` (`location_id`)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`location_id_2`) 
        REFERENCES `locations` (`location_id`)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE KEY( (LEAST(`location_id_1`, `location_id_2`)),
                (GREATEST(`location_id_1`, `location_id_2`))),
    PRIMARY KEY (`route_id`)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO locations VALUES (1), (2);
INSERT INTO routes VALUES (1,1,2);
```

```
INSERT INTO routes VALUES (2,2,1);
```

> ```
> Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'routes.functional_index'
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j1p2D7P1)

Comment: Thanks, I like the Check Constraint solution